# sudo bash install.sh -g error while installing SAP "the hostname you have chosen is not active on this server"

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, software-installation

While installing SAP on my Ubuntu following [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/03/sap-nw-as-abap-7.50-sp2-developer-edition-to-download-consise-installation-guide/).

The `sudo bash install.sh -g` command is returning the following error:

```
The hostname you have chosen is either configured on a loopback device
or not active on this server, please check your configuration and hostname selection.
If you are confident about the choice of your hostname, 
start the install script with -s flag to skip the hostname check.
```

My `/etc/hosts` has the following config:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.0.105 vhcalnplci
```

other lines are commented

`hostname` returns `vhcalnplci`

`ifconfig` returns the following:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe60:f84c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:60:f8:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 432  bytes 44014 (44.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 101  bytes 10319 (10.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 150  bytes 10747 (10.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 150  bytes 10747 (10.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please advise how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please provide a link to the application you are trying to install. If you are following any guide or installation instructions, also provide a link. Please also specify the version numbers of Ubuntu and SAP. In order to gain more attention, you may want to add the application name to your question's title.

Comment: I am installing SAP Netweaver AS ABAP 7.50 SP02 ASE Dev edition on ubuntu.
 Installation Guide link: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/03/sap-nw-as-abap-7.50-sp2-developer-edition-to-download-consise-installation-guide/

Just note that command to install SAP on ubuntu I tried was "sudo bash install.sh -g

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in install.sh, `ifconfig` don't return the text "addr"... my solution :)

```
myip=`ifconfig | egrep "inet addr" | grep Bcast | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk -F ":" '{ print $2 }'`
```

The Result :

```
myip="192.168.0.105"
```